# How to work with sessions with the BlueData REST API?

Tags: bluedata-3.7, bluedata

I would like to use the BlueData API to programmatically manage by BlueData installation.

I have seen some documentation [here](https://github.com/bluedatainc/solutions/blob/master/APIs/v2_bluedata_apis_doc.md) - it appears that I need to start off with **Fetching a session** but I would expect to create a session before I can fetch it.

How do I create a session and use that in subsequent operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Introduction

The API docs listed in the question don't show the API call for creating a session.  Instructions for creating a session can, however, be found [here](https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009338348-Login-and-Session-Creation), but I'm also adding the details in this answer in case the link goes away.

Note that you can browse the full BlueData API docs if you have a running BlueData installation:

```
http://<controller-ip>/apidocs/
```

Anyway, the steps to create a session and use the session in a subsequent call such as **Retrieve all tenants** are listed below:

### Create Session

Write the login.json file:

```sh
cat <<EOF> ./login.json
{
     "name": "admin",
     "password": "admin123"
}
EOF
```

Set the controller IP:

```sh
# Set this to your controller IP address

CONTROLLER_IP=10.0.0.1
```

You can then submit a login request:

```sh
curl -i -X POST -d@login.json http://${CONTROLLER_IP}:8080/api/v1/login
```

Returns

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
> Server: BlueData EPIC 3.7
> Location: /api/v1/session/df1bfacb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c8f57d8f3c71
> Date: Mon, 15 Jul 2019 16:47:54 GMT
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 13
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> 201 Created
> ```

Set the SESSION ID:

`SESSION_ID=/api/v1/session/df1bfacb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c8f57d8f3c71`

### Use Session to get a list of Tenants

Use the SESSION ID in a subsequent call, e.g.

```sh
curl -X GET -H "X-BDS-SESSION:${SESSION_ID}" http://${CONTROLLER_IP}:8080/api/v1/tenant
```

This example for me returns:

> ```
> {"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v1/tenant"}},...
> ```

---

See also:

- https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000519533-RESTful-APIs-Site-Admin-API-v1
- https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000518194-RESTful-APIs-Tenant-Admin